# Unsafe version of C# out parameter

Tags: c#, unsafe

The task is to write a method that initializes a declared variable like using out parameter, but using unsafe context. The unsafe code below works in C++ but it's printing 0 in C#. Can somebody help?

**UPD. The code works in Release mode.**

```
    static void InitBox(out Box box)
    {
        box = new Box(100);
    }

    unsafe static void InitBoxUnsafe(Box** box)
    {
        Box b = new Box(500);
        (*box) = &b;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //// The task is to write a code that does the same
        // Box box;
        // InitBox(out box);
        // box.Print();
        //// but using unsafe context

        //// I wrote this code, but it's not working (output is 0), can anyone tell why?
        unsafe
        {
            Box* pBox;
            Box** ppBox = &pBox;
            InitBoxUnsafe(ppBox);
            pBox->Print();
        }
    } 

    struct Box
    {
         private readonly int num;
         public Box(int number)
         {
              num = numberl
         }
         public void Print()
         {
              Console.WriteLine(num);
         }
    }
```

Comment: That *looks* like you're capturing an address on the stack in the middle of a call-chain; that is remarkably dangerous, even if it does work, no?

Comment: use [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee332485(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of `unsafe`, you don't need `unsafe` here at all

Comment: Agreed with @Mgetz.  `unsafe` is for very specific applications (like pixel functions on bitmaps).  This is a totally odd use case for `unsafe` and will certainly create many more bugs than you expect.

Comment: What is *really* fun here; for me, it works (and I use that word loosely) in "release" mode and fails in "debug"; it only works by accident ;p

Comment: Thanks guys for challenging! It was really interesting whether C# could handle that low-level code, wasn't it?

Comment: @Marc Gravell♦  - It really works in Release!!! Gonna ramble asm code ...

Comment: @IvanZ your recent comment concerns me that you don't fully understand the problem. Yes, C# can handle it just fine. The problem is: you're asking it to do something really really dangerous and silly.

Comment: @MarcGravell I assumed that the debug JIT zeroes out the stack over the stack pointer, but it doesn't seem to be so. In fact, on my computer, even in debug mode (with the debugger or not), I get "random" numbers printed out. I assume that those are caused by the `Print` method not being inlined - so the call to `Print` itself overwrites the `Box` that was on stack before. When in release mode, the method gets inlined, so the pointer still points to the same data as before. Fun.

Comment: @Luaan the runtime zeros out stack space on *entry*, but not on *exit*.

Comment: @MarcGravell I've tried walking the code in disassembly, and it seems that for some reason, in some cases, the code (in release, with debugger attached after the code is already JITted) actually zeroes out the stack before popping. And after pushing too (`push eax`, `xor eax, eax`, `mov [esp], eax`, and then finally `mov [esp], value`). It may be some compiler optimization or safety measure, but it's rather weird. In any case, on my computer, it really does inline the `Print` method, and the pointer still refers to the value `500` in memory (in an invalid part of the stack, obviously).

Comment: @Luaan sounds fun. I'm not going to worry about it too much personally: undefined behavior is undefined - interesting for curiosity value, but not much beyond that

Answer (score 5):

The code only happens to work in C++ because you're only trying it with a very simple application.

You're capturing a variable on the stack, which will be overwritten as soon as you enter another stack frame, cue a lot of funny and hard to trace errors.

The safe C# version works because it's not actually capturing the address of the local variable, it's copying its value to the frame above.

Now, you should be able to do this if you allocate unmanaged memory for the struct explicitly. Of course, if you're hoping to do this for performance reasons, this will likely make your performance much worse, and it's bound to give you tons of issues related to working with less and less safe code :)

It might also be possible to simply copy the value, rather than propagating the address out of the unsafe method, but I'd rather not mess around with that either.

So, the main question is: What's wrong with `out` and `ref`? Why are you trying to use `unsafe` code to do something that safe code can do easily and cleanly?

**EDIT:**

When working with unsafe code, it might be worth it to have a look at the assembly code actually emitted. This does not give you any guarantees, since both the C# compiler and the JIT compiler may produce different results on different computers (or possibly even on the same computer at different times), but it can give you some insight. In this case, the code in assembly can be simplified to this:

Main:

- Set [ebp - 8] (currently the top of the stack) to zero (that's basically the `Box *pBox;` line). So at [ebp - 8], we have the `pBox`.
- Pass the address of `pBox` to `InitBoxUnsafe`, in my case through `ecx` (so `ecx` now has a value of `ebp - 8`).

InitBoxUnsafe (kind of obvious, but still interesting - this is *not* inlined):

- We create a new `Box` struct on the top of the stack (basically boils down to `mov [esp], 0`, `mov [esp], 500` - allocating value types on the stack is really simple).
- Store the value `esp` in `eax` - so `eax` now has the address of our new `Box` "instance".
- And finally, store `eax` in `[ecx]` - so our `pBox` variable in `Main`'s scope now has the address of the local variable in `InitBoxUnsafe`'s scope. At this point, the pointer is still valid, and the box is still on the stack.
- As we return from the method, all of it's stack is popped.

Back to Main:

- Since we've popped `InitBoxUnsafe`'s stack, `esp` is now back where it was before the call - and `pBox` now has an address *above* the current stack pointer. The value may still be there, but the pointer is now illegal. Of course, we're in `unsafe` code, so there's noone to smack our wrist...
- There's now a different path for the release version, and the debug version:

  - In the debug version, the `Print` call is executed as usual. This involves putting a few values on the stack, most importantly the return address. However, this overwrites the value of `*pBox`, because it points to the same point in the stack. So when the `Console.WriteLine` is actually called, it will print out the return address, rather than `500`. I assume that on 64-bit, this will usually mean `0`, because that part of the return address will usually be zero, while on 32-bit, it will usually be junk.
  - In release (and without a debugger attached), the `Print` call is inlined. This means that the stack is not in fact overwritten until the `Console.WriteLine` call itself - and the value of `*pBox` is captured well before the call is made. However, doing pretty much anything that pushes on the stack between `InitBoxUnsafe` and `pBox->Print()` will destroy the value as well. In fact, just calling `pBox->Print()` twice in succession is enough - the first one will print out `500`, while the second one will print out the address of the `Console` stream, for example. Or, in case you only call a method that doesn't have any local variables or arguments, it might print out the return address.

As you can see, the code really doesn't differ much from what C++ does with the equivalent code. The differences between the output of the two (or really, running the two on different computers, or compiling them in different compilers), are due to the fact that what you're doing is illegal and undefined - behaviour you shouldn't count on. Ever.

Now, if you have a look at your second variant, where you've passed the address of `Main`'s local `box` variable instead of a pointer to a pointer, the whole pointer mumbo-jumbo is pretty much completely skipped - `InitBoxUnsafe` now simply does `mov [&box], 500` directly - a perfectly legal operation. In fact, in release mode without a debugger, `InitBoxUnsafe` can now be safely inlined, getting rid of the call completely - the whole thing now basically compiles to `Box box = (Box)500;`. Calling `Print` on `box` is now also completely safe, because the value is now firmly in scope (directly in `[ebp - 8]`, rather than in `[[ebp - 8]]`, so to speak).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I was just interesting whether this implementation will work and wondering why it does not work. So as I understand there's no way to implement that behavior in unsafe context?

Comment: @IvanZ the problem isn't that it isn't "possible" - it is that it *doesn't mean what you think it means*. It is entirely "possible" and works just fine is as much as it does what you ask. The problem is that the thing you are asking it to do is nonsensical.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right about senselessness. The question was  whether it could be implemented or not. For example to check out if I do understand pointers mechanism. I'm sorry for missing the question's actual goal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, surfing code under Reflector gave this *nice* solution that works in Debug as well as Release

```
static unsafe void InitBoxUnsafe(Box* box)
{
    *(box) = new Box(500);
}

static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
    Box box;
    InitBoxUnsafe(&box);
    box.Print(); // (&box)->Print(); // in Reflector
}
```

Comment: What you've done here is manually implement `out` - an entirely well-defined and well-understood c# concept that doesn't require `unsafe`. This is bad code. You should just use `out Box box` in the method signature, `box = new Box(500);` in the body, and `InitBoxUnsafe(out box);` at the caller. This *is* then passing pointers/references. Just: safely.

Comment: Well, the question was actually to implement `out` using `unsafe`. Just raw code without any sense. Thank you anyway for your valuable comments.

Comment: You've just copied the value of `Box` in this one, so you really are doing basically what `ref` does. The crucial lesson to learn here is that when you're manipulating values on the stack, you can only ever use pointers to the same or higher scope. In your original code, you propagated a pointer to something in a lower scope, which is forbidden (in C# as well as C++, or even assembly, really). In this code, you're initializing the `Box` structure twice - once in `Main`, and once in `InitBoxUnsafe`. `InitBoxUnsafe` then just overwrites the local variable in `Main`, which is legal.